# Obtener solo números de una cadena en Jq

Tags: bash, jq

Dadas entradas como las siguientes:

```
"+56 9 (768) 65 00"

"+56 9 678 45 00"

"+56 9 688-65-00"
```

Se busca obtener la siguiente salida:

```
"+5697686500"

"+5696784500"

"+5696886500"
```

La idea es obtener el número de teléfono sin caracteres extraños (solo el '+' al inicio).

He realizado varios intentos pero hasta el momento no me ha funcionado ninguno, en estos intentos me he enfocado unicamente en obtener los numeros, pero tampoco he podido:

**Intento 1:**

```
.phone_number | match("[0-9]"; "g") | .string
```

**Intento 2:**

```
.phone_number | match("[0-9]"; "g") | [{valor: .string}] | map(.valor) | join("")
```

**Intento 3:**

```
.phone_number | match("\\d+\") | .string
```

Comment: prueba con `("[^0-9+]")` o también `("[0-9+]+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q onda, vi que te respondió mi amigo personal chris ;). Para obtener solo los números de una cadena en JQ, pds usar la función gsub para reemplazar cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito por una cadena vacía. Por ejemplo, pds usar la siguiente expresión:

```
.phone_number | gsub("[^0-9]"; "")
```

Esto reemplazará cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito (es decir, cualquier carácter que no esté entre 0 y 9) por una cadena vacía, dejando solo los dígitos en la cadena resultante.

Por ejemplo, si aplicas esta expresión a las cadenas de ejemplo que proporcinaste, tendrias las siguientes salidas:

```
"+56 9 (768) 65 00" => "+5697686500"
"+56 9 678 45 00" => "+5696784500"
"+56 9 688-65-00" => "+5696886500"
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. Si tienes alguna pregunta adicional, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Hola Alberto, para que la salida sea exactamente la que comentas (lo que se busca efectivamente), agregue algo mas a tu solución y quedo asi y funciona bien '.phone_number | gsub("[^0-9]"; "") | "+" + .'

Muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción a la aceptada sería la de añadir un regex tipo Perl, además de añadir el simbolo de "+" a la regex:

```
jq '.phone_number | gsub("[^\\d+]"; "")'
```

Por ejemplo, si tenemos una entrada de tipo:

```
{"phone_number": "+56 9 (768) 65 00"}
{"phone_number": "+56 9 678 45 00"}
{"phone_number": "+56 9 688-65-00"}
```

La salida sería del tipo:

```
"+5697686500"
"+5696784500"
"+5696886500"
```

Ejemplo con un [*here-document*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```bash
jq '.phone_number | gsub("[^\\d+]"; "")' << _EOF
{"phone_number": "+56 9 (768) 65 00"}
{"phone_number": "+56 9 678 45 00"}
{"phone_number": "+56 9 688-65-00"}
_EOF

"+5697686500"
"+5696784500"
"+5696886500"
```